# Obtain more variables after grouping, summarising with select (dplyr)

Tags: r, select, group-by, dplyr, summarize

My data frame:

```
date  | weekday | price
2018  | 1       | 25
2018  | 1       | 35
2019  | 2       | 40
```

I try to run this code under dplyr:

```
pi %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarise(price = sum(price, na.rm = T)) %>%
  select(price, date, weekday) %>%
  print()
```

It doesn't work.

Any solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why `group_by(date)` twice? What is the error?

Comment: I am assuming you wanted `group_by(date, weekday)` in one go.

Comment: 1) `pi` is a base R constant, use `Pi`. 2) You only have 3 variables, there is no need to `select()` them. 3) `print()` is automatic. 4) `Pi %>% group_by(date, weekday) %>% summarise(price = sum (price, na.rm = T))`.

Comment: Doesn't work how?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the order: select-->group_by-->summarise

```
df%>%select(price, date, weekday)%>%
    group_by(date, weekday)%>%summarise(sum(price,na.rm=T))
```

Answer (score 0):

People are correctly suggesting to `group_by` date and weekday, but if you have a lot of columns, that could be a pain to write out.  Here's another idiom I frequently use for data.frames with lots of columns:

```
pi %>% 
  group_by(date) %>%
  mutate(price = sum(price, na.rm = T)) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1)
```

This will keep all the first instances of each column variables without having to explicitly write them all out.